# How a express to pass object to other file?

Tags: node.js, express

In app.js, when express running, express will create pool connection. then pool instance can be access in other file. How to do that?

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const mysql = require('mysql2');
const comic = require('./routes/comic');

app.use('/comics', comic);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening in ${port} port`);

  const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host:'localhost', 
    user: 'root',
    password: 'test', 
    database: 'test'
  });

  exports.connection = pool.promise();
});
```

test.js

```
const {connection} = require('./app');

(async () => {
  const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM people');
  
  console.log(rows);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a seperate db.js file that would have the connection pool and import that pool wherever necessary

In db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host:'localhost', 
    user: 'root',
    password: 'test', 
    database: 'test'
  });
module.exports = pool;
```

And in the place where u want it

```
let pool = require('./db');

const queryRes = (query, pool) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) {
            reject('Error');
        } 
        connection.query(query, (err, results, fields) => {
            if(err) {
                reject('Error');         
            }
            else{
                connection.release();
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
        connection.on('error', (err) => {
            reject('Error');
            connection.release();
        });
    });
});

queryRes("Select * from test", pool).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: if like this, its not pool concept. pool is like a server. only run 1 time.  it intermediate between request and database.  its different from normal createConnection.

Comment: So u want to call the createPool method only once right??

Comment: Yeah call 1 time, but use the pool instance in everywhere, cause i will use the pool instance in Model class. So i start the pool instance in beginning express run.

Comment: so the above one creates a single pool and shares to the whole project. You can import it wherever u want and call the getConnection function on the pool.

Comment: can do in promise ways?

Comment: yup its possible to do it using promises.... made the changes

Comment: I read from first mysql library if execute and query is shortcut of execute and release connection. `This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow.then` i try pomise way in mysql2 that already include promise wrapper. now my console hang up with result. its like not call release.